# Issue in compiling rtpengine

Tags: webrtc, sip, kamailio

Following [this](https://github.com/havfo/WEBRTC-to-SIP) I am trying to setup Kamailio + RTPEngine + TURN server to enable calling between WebRTC client and legacy SIP clients. There is a third party repository for `rtpengine` for  `Debian`. However I am trying to do this in Ubuntu 18.04.

So I decided to build from library from source. I cloned [THIS](https://github.com/sipwise/rtpengine) git repository and ran the command `dpkg-checkbuilddeps`. It have a list of unmet dependencies. I managed to install almost all, except `debhelper-compat`. The output of the above command is

```
dpkg-checkbuilddeps: error: Unmet build dependencies: debhelper-compat (= 12)
```

But if I run the command `sudo apt list | grep debhelper` the output is

```
debhelper/bionic-backports,bionic-backports,now 12.1.1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 all [installed]
```

So it means that the required package is already installed. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Some help is appreciated. I have looked in `/var/cache/apt/archives` in my machine and there is a `debhelper_11.1.6ubuntu2_all.deb` there and so `sudo apt-get install debhelper` has installed that version.

Answer (score 1):

In order to compile RTPEngine on Ubuntu follow these steps:

```
# apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential git libglib2.0-dev libavcodec-dev zlib1g-dev pkgconf perl gperf libssl-dev libevent-dev libpcap-dev libspandsp-dev libhiredis-dev libxmlrpc-core-c3-dev libmariadb-dev cmake libwebsockets-dev libavformat-dev libjson-glib-dev libavfilter-dev libcurl4-nss-dev libmariadb-dev-compat gettext-base
```

Now clone the repository:

```
# git clone https://github.com/sipwise/rtpengine
```

Build:

```
# cd rtpengine/daemon && with_iptables_option=no make
```

Now you can copy the executable daemon file, and run it (do not forget the configuration file).

PS: If you need iptables you must install the required packages and remove "with_iptables_option=no" part.